# (HTTP code 500) server error - cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-run, docker-pull

I have three custom containers in dockerhub. I created them, committed and pushed to my docker hub account. Now I pull the containers and run one by one, and one of them is not working.

This container is based on ngnix image but with custom configuration.

The error is this one:

```
(HTTP code 500) server error - cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8168d8f26efbb10c2cf46c929374e79abf59222b0788512c1800f0a61c9f48eb/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I tried deleting the volumes, then removing all containers and pulling them again and nothing seems to work.
Also tried:

```
docker run --rm -p 443:443 -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf myaccount/mycontainer:mytag -d
```

Which in theory would work but doesn't work. Any suggestion? I'm new on docker and didn't find anything in the documentations.